# Podspec fails to pass validation, but no ERROR logged

Tags: validation, dependencies, afnetworking, cocoapods

I have some apps that are quite similar. Therefore, I'd like to create a or some private pod(s) containing all common reusable code. My first version contains some networking functionality that uses AFNetworking and also uses KeychainItemWrapper:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name          = 'CommonLib'
  s.version       = '0.0.1'
  s.homepage      = '****'
  s.summary       = 'My Common lib'
  s.description   = 'Library with common code'
  s.author        = { "Rens Verhage" => "*****" }
  s.platform      = :ios, '5.0'
  s.source        = { :git => "ssh://****/CommonLib.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.source_files  = 'CommonLib/*.{h,m}'
  s.requires_arc  = true

  s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.1'
  s.dependency 'KeychainItemWrapper', '~> 1.2'
end
```

Running pod spec lint CommonLib.podspec gives a couple of WARN and NOTE messages:

```
 -> CommonLib (0.0.1)
    - WARN  | Missing required attribute `license`.
    - WARN  | Missing license type.
    - NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h:84:9: warning: SystemConfiguration framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header. Network reachability functionality will not be available. [-W#pragma-messages]
    - NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h:89:9: warning: MobileCoreServices framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header. Automatic MIME type detection when uploading files in multipart requests will not be available. [-W#pragma-messages]
    - NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  CommonLib/CommonLib/NSArray+NSArray_PerformSelector.m:19:35: warning: performSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown [-Warc-performSelector-leaks]
    - NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  CommonLib/CommonLib/NSArray+NSArray_PerformSelector.m:19:51: note: used here
    - WARN  | [iOS] Unable to find a license file

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation.
```

Notice there are no ERROR messages, but the spec doesn't pass validation however. I don't really no where to go from here. The message that the SystemConfiguration and MobileCoreServices frameworks are missing looks like an error to me. I tried fixing this warning by adding

```
s.ios.frameworks = 'MobileCoreServices', 'SystemConfiguration'
```

to my podspec, but that doesn't work.

So, two questions in one:

1. What is the error that keeps my podspec from passing validation?
2. How can I fix the warning about missing frameworks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok. Got my answer from the Cocoapods guys. Podspec validation fails on all errors and warnings. Failing on warnings doesn't mean the project fails as a Pod. Turns out I can simply  ignore the warning.

As for AFNetworking, the issue has been resolved with version 2.0.

Answer (score 14):

Recently I had this problem and adding `--allow-warnings` fixes the issue.

```
pod spec lint MyProject.podspec --allow-warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated]**

Follow  [cocoapods guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html) to configure you podspec file and resolve the error if you are getting any and while validating it, If you are getting warnings only and if you just want to ignore it then yes you can do it by running following command.

**Validating podspec with warnings**

Add`--allow-warnings`at the end it will forcefully validate podspec.

```swift
pod spec lint your_project_name.podspec --allow-warnings
```

**Push podspec repo with warnings**

Make sure that you have added your repo, if not run the following command (ignore it, if you have already added it)

```swift
pod repo add your-pods pods_git_url
```

For Pushing podspec to repo use this

```swift
pod repo push your-pods your_project_name.podspec --allow-warnings
```